# ListView OutOfMemory : External allocation too large for this process

Tags: android, listview, out-of-memory

I use a listview that loads covers I have a problem with OutOfMemory.
I use the method getView BaseAdapter for reuse cells.
I use a properly functioning imageLoader although the problem may be
related but I know it's possible.
However I disable the cache memory that is now imageLoader's current
load images but don't storage more.
When I scroll in my list at some point, I obtain in logcat the
following error:
345 600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM will not let us allocate 345,600 bytes

This error also occurs when I'm at the end of the list and I continue
to scroll, scroll the list is more or very slightly since the end is
but the same cells is shown. GetView of the BaseAdapter is not known
yet I still get the error until I scroll with my finger while the list
does not scroll over:
345 600-byte external allocation too large for this process.
VM will not let us allocate 345,600 bytes

This problem ocurred on the Archos A43, is that you know why the
system tries to allocate memory then the list does not change and
therefore does not charge the cells?
Could it come from the resources of IU?

Sincerely,

Gabriel

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, this comes from bitmaps that you are loading into `ImageView` widgets. Be sure to `recycle()` your `Bitmap` objects when you are done with them.